How to handle multiple async functions when fetching for emails and attachments with IMAP and javascript
I am using IMAP library and javascript to fetch for emails.
My plan is the following:

Fetch for the emails by email, subject, and a time range.
Look for the emails number.
For each email, I need to look for the attachments that contains PDF files.
And for each attachment, i need to build an object, push it inside an array and send it to frontend only if the function ended. It doesn't matter if I send an empty array




The problems i encounter now 
For now, I sent to the specific email two emails that contains each same pdf, and same subject.

Instead of receiving two objects inside the array, sometime I receive one, sometime I receive empty array... But never two objects like I need...




What I tried 

Defined the imap search function and before, initialised an empty array where I need to send the object after finished fetching.

Created a stream from the fetch function defined in the point above. The fetch took a message param, again as a stream.

Executed simple parser function and for each parsed document that have attachments, created an objects that will be sent to frontend.

The code
fetch.on('message', (msg) => {

                    msg.on('body', (stream) => {
                        simpleParser(stream, async (err, parsed) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            if (parsed.attachments) {
                                //defined already as an empty array    
                                attachmentPromises = parsed.attachments.map(async (attachment, index) => {
                                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                        if (attachment.contentType === 'application/pdf') {
                                            // Process the pdf here...
                                            resolve({
                                                object details with key value pairs. 
                                            });
                                        }
                                         
                                        else {
                                            resolve(null); 
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                                
                                //We wait for the promises to resolve
                                Promise.all(attachmentPromises).then(attachments => {
                                    //we get only the values that are not null
                                    const validAttachments = attachments.filter(attachment => attachment !== null);
                                    allAttachmentsData = allAttachmentsData.concat(validAttachments);
                                });

                            }
                        });
                    });
                    
                });


The fetch events
   fetch.once('error', (err) => {
                    console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
                });


                fetch.once('end', function () {
                    //allAttachmentsData is empty 
                    return res.status(200).json(allAttachmentsData);
                })


Your approach suggests you're using asynchronous operations (simpleParser and promise handling) inside the event listeners for message fetching. However, it looks like you're not ensuring all asynchronous operations complete before triggering the end event of the fetch. This could lead to timing issues where the end event is triggered before all your promises resolve.
The Promise.all function is used to handle an array of promises. However, in your code, the handling of these promises with Promise.all is done within the body event, which may not resolve before the end event of your fetch operation.
const attachmentPromises = [];

fetch.on('message', (msg) => {
  msg.on('body', (stream) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      simpleParser(stream, (err, parsed) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        if (parsed.attachments) {
          const promises = parsed.attachments.map((attachment) => {
            if (attachment.contentType === 'application/pdf') {
              // Process the pdf here...
              return {
                // Object details with key-value pairs
              };
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          });
          resolve(promises.filter(att => att !== null));
        } else {
          resolve([]);
        }
      });
    });

    attachmentPromises.push(promise);
  });
});

fetch.once('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Fetch error: ' + err);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Fetch error' });
});

fetch.once('end', () => {
  Promise.all(attachmentPromises).then(results => {
    const attachments = results.flat();
    res.status(200).json(attachments);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('Error resolving promises:', err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error processing emails' });
  });
});

